# How much do crocodiles eat?

Tags: zoology, food

How much do crocodiles eat? The closest I found to an answer was on German wikipedia, where it says that adult nile crocodiles eat "[only about 50 full meals a year.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krokodile#Jagdverhalten)" While interesting, without knowing what a full meal is this is meaningless. **So how much does an adult crocodile actually eat?**

I think relevant other questions in this context are:

- Do all adult crocodiles (or even all crocodilia) eat roughly the same (corrected for body mass)?
- Some crocodiles apparantly [eat fruit and seeds on a regular basis](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/jzo.12052/abstract)*, is this is a relevant part of their caloric intake or just a "vitamin supplement"?

*paywalled article, I only read the abstract

Comment: re the close vote: a) I've added the additional questions because I don't think one can answer the question meaningful without at least adressing them (but could be wrong) b) a comment why exactly the vote to close would be appreciated.

Comment: fwiw, english wikipedia on crocodilia states "10-20% of what a lion needs" witht this paywalled source: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1469-7998.1986.tb01518.x/abstract someone with access could use this maybe?

Comment: full meal= bloating with days of digestion